# asp.net core: "Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mysql-connector

My server uses MySqlConnector and communicates with a MySQL database on AWS.  I store 5 minute chunks of API counters in MySQL.  Those API counters are incrementing with each API call, and are handled by ConcurrentDictionary code (which doesn't appear to be a problem).  An exception was recently raised by this line of code, which is part of a linq query through MySqlConnector to access a MySQL database table:

`await _context.ApiCounts.Where(c => c.ApiName == apiName && c.StartTime >= startTime).ToListAsync();`

I've never seen this line fail before, but suddenly one of my servers started throwing the following exception at the line above:

```
InvalidOperationException: Operations that change non-concurrent collections must have exclusive access. A concurrent update was performed on this collection and corrupted its state. The collection's state is no longer correct.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ConcurrentOperationsNotSupported
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.NodeTypeProviders.MethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistry.GetNodeType
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.NodeTypeProviders.MethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistry.IsRegistered
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.GetQueryOperatorExpression
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.SubQueryFindingExpressionVisitor.Visit
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary
at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary
at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept
at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListPartitionIterator`2.ToArray
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.MethodCallExpressionParser.Parse
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.ExpressionTreeParser.ParseMethodCallExpression
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileAsyncQueryCore
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass24_0`1.<CompileAsyncQuery>b__0
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator
at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable+<Aggregate_>d__6`3.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
at BlayFap.Controllers.ServerController+<GetCachedApiCount>d__13.MoveNext (E:\Projects\BlayFap\BlayFap\Controllers\ServerController.cs:342)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
at BlayFap.Controllers.ServerController+<GetApiCount>d__14.MoveNext (E:\Projects\BlayFap\BlayFap\Controllers\ServerController.cs:378)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
```

All of the other tables can be accessed fine, but from here on any attempt to use the ApiCounts table results in the above exception.  I had to actually reboot the affected server to clear the error.  It looks like this exception has to do with concurrent edits on a Dictionary, and that Dictionary appears to be in linq code.  I'm guessing that the server may have gotten caught in a situation where EF was both updating and writing some sort of data while executing a linq statement, and then got the Dictionary stuck in a weird state, but I'm not sure how to protect against this and where the real issue is.  Is this a .NET bug, or my own?

More info: I do not modify the result from ApiCounts in this function, and I do not call SaveChanges.  It is, however, possible for code running async to this (in another REST query) to update ApiCounts and call SaveChanges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to update to EF 2.1.5 or newer.

I was using EF 2.0.3 when this error occurred.  It looks like there was a thread unsafe singleton, which could result in the same error I saw.  Here's the issue in github:  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12682

Comment: I think the solution is to upgrade to at least EF Core 2.1.3: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commit/166e6014791e59c9f0937b05498c82f12cd559b2

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this particular issue by changing the registration of Dependency Injection from Singleton to Transient. The reason for the issue is basically as we have registered our repository or context singleton and we are using the same scope in multiple threads and that's why one thread will not be able to find the resource and that's why throw an exception by switching to transient we create scopes for every thread that's why solve the case.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i had the same issue. after spending hours, i restarted the application pool in IIS it started working like a charm.

First I tried to duplicate the issue in different environment. It occurred only in PROD environment. So I restarted the IIS application pool which gave me the expected output

Comment: Restarting the application pool never *fixes* anything. The exception will come back soon.

Comment: Hello @GertArnold, Okay. May be. let me wait for the issue to come back. i'll update if issue reopens

Comment: same issue with me.  and restart worked.  we had loaded some code with a bad config, and reloading with the config corrected left it in a bad state of some kind.  restarting the app service in Azure indeed fixed this issue in this case.